# How do galaxies move through space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, vacuum, galaxies

If we assume that galaxies only consist of planets, stars, and space, then how do galaxies move through space?

How do you move empty space, or is it that space remains same, but the planets, stars, and other things are moving through space-time? Won't a moving galaxy distort the space-time fabric?

Comment: In relation to what observer? Spacetime is relative to an observer, not an absolute invariant thing.

Answer (score 4):

It might help to clarify your thinking if you could say why you picked galaxies as your example. The same question could be asked about anything: a ball, a paperclip, a pen, a cat.

Things move through space but they don't "move through spacetime"; rather they have extension in both spatial and temporal directions in spacetime.

Everything distorts spacetime by gravitation. This distortion is largest near the worldline of each object, and falls away with distance in the spatial direction.